# iPhone - Three220 - TTScrollView : Dead store analyzed result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I've just moved my project to XCode 4 from Xcode 3 and see this Dead Store in TTScrollView class:

```
- (CGFloat)tween:(NSTimeInterval)t b:(NSTimeInterval)b c:(NSTimeInterval)c d:(NSTimeInterval)d 
{  
      return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;  
}
```

The warning is:

"Although the value stored to 't' is used in the enclosing expression, the value is never actually read from 't'"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at

```
c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
```

You are redefining `t`! I don't think this is what you mean to be doing here. Perhaps `==`? Or perhaps you just mean `c*((t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;`?